# invalid add-on error while installing gmail addons

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am trying to install my gmail addons on another gmail account and getting "Invalid addons" error message.

[image]

I have selected "Enable developer add-ons for my account" checkbox and provided id.

It is already working on my main gmail account on which i have written appscript code.

Does anyone have this kind of issue?

Comment: You should ask this question on the Google community:  [Developing add-ons for G Suite](https://plus.google.com/communities/117193953428311185494)

Comment: Thanks sandy for addressing google community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need to give read access to add-on's script project in order to install an add-on for @gmail.com.

It is already provided in the doc.

Comment: where document says like that "in order to install an add-ons for @gmail.com." me too got same problem

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment so answering, you need to share the Project folder from Google drive with the email who's trying to install your add-on.

This wouldn't restrict the user from accessing your code, as far as I can tell.